# What are the differences between levels of the Vintage Pyrovision Goggles?

Tags: team-fortress-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the item level in Team Fortress 2 affect the particular item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8459/does-the-item-level-in-team-fortress-2-affect-the-particular-item)

Is there any difference in functionality between levels of Vintage Pyrovision Goggles, or are the levels only useful for trading value?
(mine are Level 23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, item levels are completely auxiliary. They have no gameplay effect and I don't even think most traders care about them.

Answer (score 4):

Item levels exist for collectors to obsess about. Special numbers tend to be more sought-after than others, such as 1, 77, 99, or 100.

Often times these collectors will try to obtain a full set of gear with matching levels. So...there is no difference between any items based on level other than what people attribute to them.